# Как настроить поле «file_regex» в настройках проекта Sublime Text для GCC?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++builder, gcc, sublime-text

Пытался установить и использовать плагин "[Highlight Build Errors](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Highlight%20Build%20Errors)", он у меня не заработал и оказалось что возможная проблема в том, что я в настройках проекта не указывал значение "file_regex". Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в синтаксисе задания этого регулярного выражения, но не понимаю как это правильно написать. Вот пример из стандартной документации:

```
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
```

Но, к сожаления это не подошло. Подскажите как правильно настроить этот параметр? 
У меня вот например в логе построения проекта ошибки отображаются в таком виде:

```
    --- compiling .\user-code/main.c...
.\user-code/main.c: In function 'main':
.\user-code/main.c:44:2: error: expected ')' before '{' token
  {
  ^
.\user-code/main.c:54:1: error: expected expression before '}' token
 }
 ^
```